# Can I use the set of "used arguments values" as a memoization key for a deterministic function?

Tags: algorithms, correctness-proof, memoization

I have a deterministic function $f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ that takes $n$ arguments.

Given a set of arguments $X = (x_i)$, I can compute $U_X = \{ i \in [1, n] : x_i \text{ was read during the evaluation of } f(X) \}$

Would it be valid to use the set $K_X = \{(i, x_i): i \in U_X\}$ as a memoization key for $f(X)$?

In particular, I am worried that there may exist $X=(x_i)$ and $Y=(y_i)$ such that:

$$
\tag1 U_X \subset U_Y
$$
$$
\tag2 \forall i \in U_X, x_i = y_i
$$
$$
\tag3 f(X) \neq f(Y)
$$

In my case, the consequence of the existence of such $X$ and $Y$ would be that $K_X$ would be used as a memoization key for $f(Y)$, and would thus return the wrong result.

My intuition says that, with $f$ being a deterministic function of its arguments, there should not even exist $X$ and $Y$ (with $U_X$ a strict subset of $U_Y$) such that both $(1)$ and $(2)$ hold (much less all three!), but I would like a demonstration of it (and, if it turns out to be trivial, at least pointers to the formalism that makes it trivial).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as $f$ is deterministic and depends only on its arguments (not on other global variables), yes, you can safely use that as a memoization key.  The bad case cannot happen.

You can see this by thinking about what happens as it reads the $t$th argument and using induction on $t$.  Let $i_1,i_2,i_3,\dots,i_t$ be the sequence of argument indices read (i.e., $f$ first reads $i_1$ when running on input $x$, then reads $i_2$, etc.).  For each $t$, if $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ have behaved the same up until just before they read the $t$th of these, then the next index examined by $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ will be the same, say $i_t$; if additionally $x_{i_t} = y_{i_t}$, then it follows $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ will behave the same up until just before they read the $t+1$st of their arguments.  Since $i_t \in U_X$, $x_{i_t} = y_{i_t}$ is guaranteed by your assumptions. Now use induction.

This assumes everything is deterministic.  For instance, $f$ had better not be allowed to read a random-number generator, the current time of day, or other global variables.  Beware that on some platforms there can be surprising sources of non-determinism, e.g., due to aspects of behavior that are unspecified and might depend on external factors.  For instance, I have a recollection that floating-point math in Java can introduce non-determinism in some cases, and so if you want to write code that is verifiably deterministic, you probably want to avoid all floating-point math.

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate $f$ by what is known in complexity theory as a *decision tree*. Each node is labelled by an input $x_i$, and the edges going downwards are labelled by the possible values of $x_i$. Leaves are labelled by the output of $f$. For decision trees you can prove your claim by induction on the height of the decision tree.

This reduces what you want to show to fleshing out the claim that $f$ can be simulated by a decision tree. If you have a computing formalism then you can prove this by induction on the length of the program, but we don't normally do that in complexity theory. We just spend a few seconds thinking about the matter, and see that the claim is obvious, and go on with our life.